# Trope about the hot desert sun makes a high pitched squealy noise

Tags: sound-effects

I recently heard a noise described as "sounding like those movie scenes where someone is stranded in the hot desert and they look up at the sun and there is this high pitched squealing noise", and this completely made sense to me. But, upon reflection and some searches for such scenes, I'm not finding a good example. Sometimes the dramatic music has such tones, but not really in the way I'm remembering, where it was just a non-musical soundscape. I had taken it for granted that it was common for the desert sun to be associated with this high pitched squealy sound. Why did this person's description of this sound resonate with me?

(A more general discussion could be had about cliche sound effects that represent things that don't actually make that sound in reality - the desert sun doesn't make a squealing noise, swords don't really go "schwing" when they are pulled from their scabbard, etc.)

Any thoughts on the existence/origins of this trope? The site tvtropes.org has a [section on desert tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DesertTropes), but I don't find any reference to this sound effect, and of course I've checked this SE site and haven't found it here.

I'm hoping this doesn't get smacked down as an "identification" question, but I would love to hear about some good examples!

Comment: @Giacomo1968, sizzling meat is a happy good sound, like fajitas. This is more like sci-fi laser beams coming from the sun, remorselessly declaring the impending doom of the sufferer.

Comment: At this point it is like asking us why you (and the person having described that sound) have that particular association. Sorry, but this looks like both an ID- and an opinion-based question to me.

Comment: Not id but opinion based imo.

Comment: When I think of this trope, it’s music, not a sound effect. I’ve always thought it dated back to *Lawrence of Arabia* and the brilliant score by Maurice Jarre. There’s a moment in the music like this during the crossing of the Nefud. One extreme comedic example is in *Spaceballs*. I would say this is not opinion based because it’s definitely a trope used over the years. Pretty sure Ren & Stimpy have used it also. It’s **definitely** in *Spaceballs* which is free with ads on YouTube at this time. But I think this is an ID question.

Comment: I just realized there is a non-musical example of a literal squealing sun: Baby Sun from “Teletubbies”. <shudder>

Comment: I don't understand how this can be an opinion? it either exists or it doesn't.

Comment: It's not opinion based, it's definitely answerable if such scenes do exist, though I can't think of any.  Though to be honest it probably is an "example list" type question

Comment: I absolutely know what you mean with that question @BrianStamper... it's this threatening noise, loud, almost screaming, when someone looks into the sun in a desert... Ithinks this should be reopened as it definitively is answerable, although I can't name a movie where it is in... probably Western movies?

Comment: Is there some overlap with the sound accompanying lasers or other bright beams of light (as in e.g. [The Man With The Golden Gun](https://youtu.be/wADpzJ0XmH0?t=86))?